# Parse URL in Ruby to get subdomain or main domain without "www"?

Tags: ruby

If I had an URL:

```
http://www.example.com/page
```

I would like to interpret that to:

```
example.com
```

But, if I had:

```
http://blog.example.com/page
```

I'd like to get back:

```
blog.example.com
```

Is that difficult?

Comment: Note that `www.example.com` is not necessarily equivalent to `example.com` for a given domain. (This is true in practice, not just in theory.)

Comment: The resulting domain is not going to be used for anything other than display, but thanks for the heads-up

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use Ruby's [URI](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI.html) module:

```
require 'uri'
URI.parse('http://www.example.com/page').host
=> "www.example.com"
URI.parse('http://blog.example.com/page').host
=> "blog.example.com"
```

In both cases, URI extracts the whole host name, because selectively stripping the host from the domain makes no sense.

You'll have to implement that logic separately, using something like:

```
%w[http://www.example.com/page http://blog.example.com/page].each do |u|
  puts URI.parse(u).host.sub(/^www\./, '')
end
```

Which outputs:

```
example.com
blog.example.com
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [`URI` class](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI.html); for example:

```
require 'uri'
uri1 = URI.parse("http://www.example.com/page")
puts uri1.host.gsub(/www\./i, "") #This will print example.com
uri2 = URI.parse("http://blog.example.com/page")
puts uri2.host #This prints blog.example.com
```

`gsub` will simply replace `"www"`, case insensitive, for `""`.

Comment: `.gsub(/www\./i, "")` will also output `'foowww.com'.gsub(/www\./i, "")
=> "foocom"`

Comment: Because you don't expect that `www.` will appear multiple times in url, you can use `sub` that has better performance.

Answer (score -1):

```rb
URI.parse(url).host.gsub(/\Awww./,"")
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).